Adding horizontal blank space in listing
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}

\lstset{columns=fullflexible}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
        \item \textbf{Symbolic representations}
        \begin{lstlisting}[mathescape, columns=fullflexible, basicstyle=\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont]
            >>> pi 
            $\pi$ 
            >>> sqrt(2)
            $\sqrt2$
            >>> a = sqrt(2)
            >>> a.evalf()             # evaluate in floaing point number
            1.41421356237310
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}

How do I add blank space before # evaluate in floaing point number? I can't use verbatim since I need mathematical symbols inside my codes.
EDIT: As yannisl suggested, removing autogobble package and changing columns=fullflexible to flexible do the job. But at the same time, the alignment changes from left to somewhere middle. I need to fix the alignment to left of the page. Also the unneeded code are removed.

Similar question: spacing - listings bug: space after literate replacement lost with spaceflexible/fullflexible columns - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange (solution there works here verbatim though)

Remove the autogobble and use any spacing you want. mathescape implies you use $ $ to escape has nothing to do with #. Your MWE is swimming also in a lot of unneeded code. Please reduce.

@yannisl I removed autogobble=true. But the texts after # is still not being moved

You need to remove the package alltogether, as well as columns=fullflexible then just use a space to adjust to what you want.

It's quite awkward to post an answer of my own question, but I think this would reduce the number of unanswered questions of this community.
I tried some combinations with autogobble and fullflexible and found that to keep texts left aligned, autogobble is required but to adjust manual spaces between words, flexible is required in place of fullflexible.
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}

\lstset{autogobble=true, columns=flexible}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
        \item \textbf{Symbolic representations}
        \begin{lstlisting}[mathescape, columns=flexible, basicstyle=\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont]
            >>> pi 
            $\pi$ 
            >>> sqrt(2)
            $\sqrt2$
            >>> a = sqrt(2)
            >>> a.evalf()             # evaluate in floaing point number
            1.41421356237310
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}

